# Object list index is not being updated: Index Error: list

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, for-loop, indexing

I have a class which I will keep omit unimportant information:

```
class BuildMap:
def __init__(self):
    #Constructor
    self.nodes = []

def indexmap(self):
        for node in self.nodes:
            print(int(node),":",nodes[node])

def delnode(self,num):
    del self.nodes[num]
    for edge in self.edges:
        if num in self.edges[edge]:
            self.edges[edge].remove(num)
    del self.edges[num] #Deletes the list associated with the number
    del nodes[int(num)] #Deleted the word associated with the node number
    for dist in list(self.distance.keys()):
        if num in dist:
            del self.distance[dist]
```

Outside of the class:

```
def delnode():
    print("Please specify the city you would like to remove: ")
    GPSMap.indexmap()
    num = input("City Number: ")
    if int(num) >= len(nodes):
        print("Sorry that number does not match")
        delnode()
    GPSMap.delnode(int(num))
```

The problem I am having is that after deleting one "node" and doing all the code I've made to clean up my other data structures I receive

```
File "C:/Users/gibbo/PycharmProjects/main.py", line 52, in indexmap
print(int(node),":",nodes[node])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have done some debugging and noticed my index isn't stopping with the length of the list and is going past after an node has been deleted as if the index hasn't been updated or my for loop:

```
for node in self.nodes:
```

Isn't using the number of nodes in the list as the index.

Comment: `nodes[node]` should probably be `self.nodes[node]` in line ~8

Comment: `node` is already a node, not an index; you don't need to do `nodes[node]` or `self.nodes[node]` to get the node.

Comment: @ryugie
Should clarify this one nodes is something different it's a list of names, I wanted to map the nodes (numbers) to nodes (names) so the index's are 1:1

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  Your posted code is improperly indented; even if that is fixed, it does not reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**node** is a *node*, not an integer.  Since you haven't included the definition of the object, we don't know what happens when you convert it to an integer, but I'm pretty sure you're not going to like the result.  When you use that as an index, the result is almost certain to be well outside the range of your list.

To see the actual effect, separate your print statement:

```
print(int(node))
print(nodes[node])
```

Overall, you should recognize that **node** is the node from the list, not its position in the list.  Use **node** directly as the object you want.

Comment: The nodes are indexed as follows:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] I chose to use nodes instead of a number because of if I remove say '3' from the list so I would get the position of the node in the list however I'm thinking that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
def indexmap(self):
        for node in self.nodes:
#  list elem -^      ^- list
            print(int(node),":",nodes[node])
#                                      ^- It should be int, not elem.
```

so, fix it.

```
def indexmap(self):
    for (i,node) in enumerate(self.nodes):
        print("{}:{}".format(i, node))
```